# Find n minimum.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $100$
countries participating in an Olympiad. Suppose $n$
is a positive integer such that each of the $100$
countries is willing to communicate in exactly $n$
languages. If each set of $20$
countries can communicate in at least one common language, and no language is common to all $100$
countries, what is the minimum possible value of $n$
?

I have tried to solve this, and I am getting $n\ge 21$,
This problem is from RMO 2016,the correct answer is $20$.

Please give easy solution.

Comment: Probably I do not understand. We have 100 countries, and 100 languages $L_1$ to $L_{100}$; Imagine all countries has decided to communicate in languages $L_1$ to $L_{20}$, except one specific country, who communicates with language $L_{21}$ to $L_{40}$ . All sets which have this specific country will be unable to communicate. So the correct answer is 51.

Comment: @Lourrran:  That shows the answer is at least $51$ but does not show that is enough.  Divide the languages into five groups of $20$ and let each country speak the $80$ languages from four groups.  Now take one country that doesn't speak each group and they cannot communicate, so $n \ge 81$

Comment: @Lourrran I think the question is asking for the smallest $n$ for which it is still *possible* that the countries' language selections is such that every set of 20 countries has a common language. You seem to be looking for the lowest $n$ for which it all language selections work, whereas the question wants the lowest $n$ for which at least one language selection works.

Comment: The problem and its "solution" are online [here](https://www.resonance.ac.in/answer-key-solutions/RMO/2016/Answer-Key-Solution.aspx) as Problem 4 of the Series 5 (Rajasthan, Chhattisgarh, Jharkhand & Orrisa Region) version of RMO-2016.  The problem does not directly say how many languages are involved, and the "solution" begins summarily, "Let there be 20 languages everybody speaks."  Further reading of the "solution" suggests to me that it was assumed $n$ is the same as the number of languages available.  But this doesn't seem to be implied by the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1550309p9424510), if my answer and this collides, please just use their answer.

My own answer is like this:

The answer is $20$. Suppose there are $21$ languages, $20$ major and $1$ minor. For each of the $20$ major languages, exactly one of the countries (we call it odd countires) does not speak it, and they can speak the minor language. So if there are $\le 19$ odd countries and some other countries picked, one of the major language can be spoken among them. If all the odd countries picked, they can speak the minor language.

$19$ is not okay, since if there is one country speak $19$ languages, we can pick other $19$ (possible same, but same is better) countries such that they cannot speak each of the language this country says.